# Как я могу обновить json внутри list в Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть:

```
create table test(id serial, content jsonb);

insert into test(content) values ("[{"amount": 100, "userId": 1}, {"amount": 200, "userId": 2}]");

select * from test;
 id |                           content                            
----+-------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | [{"amount": 100, "userId": 1}, {"amount": 200, "userId": 2}]
```

Как я могу получить:

```
 id |                           content                            
----+-------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | [{"amount": 100, "userId": 1}, {"amount": 300, "userId": 2}]
```

Мне нужно обновить ключ `amount` где `userId` = 2 на 300.
Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: С такой структурой JSON это будет сделать довольно проблематично. Возможно стоит ее немного переделать. Например, сделать так чтобы **id** пользователя был ключом для записей с информацией.
Если же структуру изменить нельзя, то вероятней всего нужно будет писать хранимую процедуру, которая будет получать JSON целиком, проходить по нему и менять поля погласно условию. И потом уже использовать эту хранимую процедуру.

Comment: [newman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/198238/newman), Я думал об этом, но это же будет плохо по скорости?(хранимые процедуры) Проблема в том, что к этой табличке люди будут обращаться чаще всего, поэтому скорость важна.

Поправьте меня пожалуйста, ежели я где то не прав.

Comment: Хранимая процедура не так уж и медленно будет. Но в любом случае, если еще не поздно, возможно стоит подумать о переделке структуры JSON. А вообще может быть и о переделке структуры данных.  Не очень понятно зачем вам тут JSON. Возможно стоит завести дополнительную таблицу и хранить данные в ней. И менять их можно будет простым UPDATE.